# update a constraint with Pulp

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp

Suppose to have a linear program and a constraint of the form:

```
4 x_1 + 3 x_2 ≤ 10
```

and that you want to update it to

```
4 x_1 + 3 x_2 + 10 x_3 ≤ 10
```

or to

```
3 x_2 ≤ 10
```

In order to do that, I "rewrite" the constraint from scratch, like

```
prob.constraints[0] = ...
```

but for a very long constraint this is very inefficient.

Is there a simpler way to add or remove variables from the constraints?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add new terms to your constraints by:

```
prob.constraints[0].addterm(x_3, 10)
```

Similarly you can remove terms by

```
prob.constraints[0].pop(x_1)
```

This accomplishes the two examples you listed.